# faster algorithms for minimum maximum contiguous k partition

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

I was reading this [http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~terlaky/4-6TD3/slides/DP/DP.pdf](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/%7Eterlaky/4-6TD3/slides/DP/DP.pdf) and would like to know if there exists a solution with better time complexity to the partition problem.

From the link:

> "Suppose a given arrangement S of non-negative numbers
> {s1,...,sn} and an integer k. How to **cut** S into k or fewer ranges,
> so as to minimize the maximum sum over all the ranges?"

e.g.

> S = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
>
> k=3
>
> By cutting S into these 3 ranges, the sum of the maximum range (8,9) is 17, which is the minimum possible.
>
> 1,2,3,4,5|6,7|8,9

The algorithm suggested in the link runs in O(kn^2) and uses O(kn) space. Are there more efficient algorithms?

Comment: This is a dynamic programming problem. Rather than running in exponential time it optimizes the solution to be in only polynomial time. This is very good, so I don't think you have to search for a "more efficient" solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so apparently this was closed for being "off-topic"!?
But it's back up now so anyway, I found the solution to be binary searching the answer. Sorry I forgot one of the constraints was that the sum of all the integers would not exceed 2^64. So let C = cumulative sum of all integers. Then we can binary search for the answer using a

`bool isPossible(int x)`

function which returns true if it is possible to divide S into k partitions with maximum partition sum less than X. isPossible(int x) can be done in O(n) (by adding everything from left to right and if it exceeds x make a new partition). So the total running time is O(n*log(s)).