# How to partition an array of integers in a way that minimizes the maximum of the sum of each partition?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, partitioning

The inputs are an array A of positive or null integers and another integer K.

We should partition A into K blocks of consecutive elements (by "partition" I mean that every element of A belongs to some block and 2 different blocks don't contain any element in common).

We define the sum of a block as sum of the elements of the block.

The goal is to find such a partition in K blocks such that the maximum of the sums of each block (let's call that "*MaxSumBlock*") is minimized.

We need to output the MaxSumBlock (we don't need to find an actual partition)

Here is an example:

Input:

```
A = {2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2}
K = 3
```

Expected output:

```
MaxSumBlock: 6
(with partition: {2, 1}, {5, 1}, {2, 2, 2})
```

In the expected output, the sums of each block are 3, 6 and 6. The max is 6.

Here is an non optimal partition:

```
partition: {2, 1}, {5}, {1, 2, 2, 2}
```

The sums of each block in that case are 3, 6 and 7. The max is hence 7. It is not a correct answer.

What algorithm solves this problem?

EDIT: K and the size of A is no bigger than 100'000. Each element of A is no bigger than 10'000

Comment: what are the constraints on the size of the array and K?

Comment: Just edited my question

Comment: Dynamic programming (with increasing A and K)?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I thought of DP but it seems to me the complexity is N^2 which seems too much for 100k

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659543

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use binary search.

Let max sum range from 0 to sum(array). So, mid = (range / 2). See if mid can be achieved by partitioning into `k` sets in O(n) time. If yes, go for lower range and if not, go for a higher range.

This will give you the result in O(n log n).

PS: if you have any problem with writing the code, I can help but I'd suggest you try it first yourself.

EDIT:
as requested, I'll explain how to find if `mid` can be achieved by partitioning into `k` sets in O(n) time.

Iterate through the elements till sum is less than or equal to `mid`. As soon as it gets greater than `mid`, let it be part of next set. If you get `k` or less sets, `mid` is achievable, else not.

Comment: "See if mid can be achieved by partitioning into k sets in O(n) time." - How? Please elaborate on that or the answer is a bit incomplete. (I think I know how, but it may not be obvious to everyone)

Comment: We can also determine a lower bound of the max sum range: max(array).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought about finding a minimal partition given a MaxSumBlock, but I don't know why I haven't thought about the obvious solution to simply walk the array

Comment: Shouldn't the time complexity here be `O(n log range)`?