# Partition a set of numbers to at most K groups, such that the max of group sums is minimized

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking, partition

Given a list of non-negative numbers, we can partition these numbers into at most `K` groups. We take the sum of each group, then take the max of these sums, and we wish to minimize the largest sum.

```
f: (nums: List[int], K: int) -> int  

For example: Given nums = [1,2,4,5,7,8], K = 3. Result is 9.
Since groups = [[1,8],[2,7],[4,5]], max(1+8,2+7,4+5) = 9
```

Edge case would be `K >= len(nums)`, since we can put one number each group.

```py
def partition(nums: List[int], K: int) -> int:
    '''\
        len(nums) >= 1, nums[i] >= 0, K > 0
        we partition nums into groups, len(groups) <= K  
        we wish to minimize max(map(sum, groups))  
    '''
    if K >= len(nums):
        return max(nums)
```

[Solution] As mentioned in comments, there's a subtle difference between this one and the question mentioned as duplicate, so I've coded the solution below.

```py
from typing import *
import math

def partition(lst: List[int], K: int) -> int:
    '''\
        Time: O(logN * K * N ^ 2), Space: O(N)
        logN for binary search, and KN^2 for backtrack search
    '''

    if K >= len(lst):
        return max(lst)

    total = sum(lst)
    low = math.ceil(total / K)
    high = total

    def canfit(lst, topbar, K):
        groups = [0] * K
        is_taken = [False] * len(lst)

        def helper(idx_lst, idx_group):
            if idx_lst == len(lst):
                return True
            elif idx_group == len(groups):
                return False
            else:
                for i, num in enumerate(lst):
                    if not is_taken[i] and groups[idx_group] + num <= topbar:
                        groups[idx_group] += num
                        is_taken[i] = True
                        if helper(idx_lst+1, idx_group):
                            return True
                        is_taken[i] = False
                        groups[idx_group] -= num
                if helper(idx_lst, idx_group+1):
                    return True

        return helper(0, 0)

    res = None
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if canfit(lst, mid, K):
            res = mid
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1

    return res

assert partition([1,4,2,8,5,7], 3) == 9
assert partition([1], 2) == 1
```

Comment: Your edge case is incorrect: when `k > len(nums)` then you must return `max(nums)`

Comment: Edge case modified. Thanks, pLOPeGG.

Comment: if k = 2 then what should be your answer is it we should make groups like `[8,4,1]` and `[7,5,2]` so that resulting answer of `13`

Comment: I guess your problem is NP-hard (probably a reduction from 3-partition). If you want to quickly have a solution, I would suggest some LP solver (the program should be quite easy to encode).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437090/how-to-partition-an-array-of-integers-in-a-way-that-minimizes-the-maximum-of-the  here's an O(N^2 * logN) solution using binary search and backtrack.

Comment: You just want the value and not the actual partition?

Comment: @Olf yes, just the min of each subgroup's sum.

Comment: @AnkitKumarNamdeo: in your example, the answer is 14 (the maximum is for 7+5+2=14)

Comment: In the question mentioned as *duplicate*, the elements in a block must be consecutive, and the proposed solution uses this constraint. This constraint is not indicated in this question.